# Is it possible to draw a feature on a MapContent object (layer) in Geotools at runtime?

Tags: geospatial, geotools

I am working on Geotools and trying to edit an existing layer at run time.
Basically I have a layer which I have added on to a MapContent object, which I then project it on JFrame. Now what I want to know is that can we manually draw some features on this showing on JFrame to edit this layer by drawing some features( which could be either a point or a polygon).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is perfectly possible. You will need a [Swing tool](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/unsupported/swing/index.html) to handle the drawing and then some way to add any needed attributes to the geometry to make a new `feature` (see [`SimpleFeatureBuilder`](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/feature/simple/SimpleFeatureBuilder.html)) and then add that to the layer.